# Prevent Google from creating pages from links on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pretty weird issue going on with my site right now. I have a "send this product to a friend" popup window that comes up on my product pages. This window is a popup, but has it's on seperate html page that is called and put into the pop up, as seen here:

Here is the link that the user would click to trigger the popup:

```
<li><a class="email-friend" rel="nofollow"></a></li>
```

And here is the jquery to get the popup to show:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.email-friend-popup').jqm();
            jQuery('a.email-friend').click(function(){

               jQuery.ajax("/catalog/send.html?productId=<?= $product->entity_id; ?>", {
                    data: {},
                    success: function(data, status, xhr){

                        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.email-friend-popup').html(data); }, 1000);
                             //jQuery('#jqmHide').click(function(){ jQuery('#jqmWindow').jqmHide(); });
                     }
                });

               jQuery('.email-friend-popup').html('<img src="/media/island/loading.gif" />').jqmShow();
               return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

When Google crawls my page, it creates a link like this: /catalog/send.html?product=3791. And with a couple hundred products on our site, it's causing quite an SEO issue. As you can see, I've added rel="nofollow" to the a tag but that doesn't seem to be resolving the issue since the pages still exist. Does anyone know about this issue or have a solution that may resolve it?

You can see the popup working here: http://www.islandcompany.com/catalog/mens-resort-wear/classic-shirts/bimini-striped-linen-shirt.html

And here is the page that is being created as a result of this bug: http://www.islandcompany.com/catalog/send.html?product=7871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "robots" meta tag to /catalog/send.html:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

More info: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent Google Bot (and other search engines' bots) to crawl your page(s) by using the robots.txt file ([more info here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)) that you place at the root of your website (www.example.com/robots.txt).

You can write something like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /catalog/send.html
```

The url will be removed from Google index (after a certain amount of time), you can force this by using one of the tools provided at [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=fr) (the "URL removal" tool under "Google Index" section).

Comment: Yeah I just read up on that. Could you also add this meta tag on the send page?

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

Comment: Yes, I think it should work (but be sure to place it only on this page). The benefit of the robots.txt is that everything is in the same place.